# Color of side note change when adding highlighting on crossline text (with the soul package)

Tags: color, highlighting, sidenotes

Just as shown in the following picture, when I highlight the crossline text, the color of the text in side note of the same line is also changed.

[image: Problem description]

The code is as following:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color, xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{ a4paper,   total={10cm,257mm},  left=10mm,  top=20mm, }
\begin{document}
\setlength\marginparwidth{8cm} 
\setlength\marginparsep{0.6cm} 
aaa 
\sethlcolor{yellow}\hl{bbb}\marginpar{\scriptsize{\textbf{bbb:}}} 
ccc dddd eeee ffff ggggg hhhhhh iiiiiii jjjjjjjj \
\sethlcolor{yellow}\hl{kkkkkkkkk kkkkkkkkkkk}
\marginpar{\scriptsize{\textbf{kkkkkkkkk kkkkkkkkkkk:} }}

aaa 
\sethlcolor{yellow}\hl{bbb}\marginpar{\scriptsize{\textbf{bbb:} }}
ccc dddd eeee ffff ggggg hhhhhh iiiiiii jjjjjjjj 
\sethlcolor{pink}
\hl{kkkkkkkkk kkkkkkkkkkk}
\marginpar{\scriptsize{\textbf{kkkkkkkkk kkkkkkkkkkk:} }}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: reset the color in the marginpar: `\marginpar{\normalcolor...`

Comment: Yeah, resetting the color is working. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you reset the color with `\marginpar{\normalcolor...` you get a bad alignment.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color, xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
  \geometry{ a4paper,   total={10cm,257mm},  left=10mm,  top=20mm, }

\makeatletter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
  \patchcmd{\@savemarbox}{\color@vbox}{\color@vbox\normalcolor}{}{}
\makeatother
    
\begin{document}
 \setlength\marginparwidth{8cm} 
 \setlength\marginparsep{0.6cm} 

 aaa 
 \sethlcolor{yellow}\hl{bbb}\marginpar{\scriptsize{\textbf{bbb:}}} 
 ccc dddd eeee ffff ggggg hhhhhh iiiiiii jjjjjjjj \
 \sethlcolor{yellow}\hl{kkkkkkkkk kkkkkkkkkkk}
 \marginpar{\scriptsize{\textbf{kkkkkkkkk kkkkkkkkkkk:} }}
 
 aaa 
 \sethlcolor{yellow}\hl{bbb}\marginpar{\scriptsize{\textbf{bbb:} }}
 ccc dddd eeee ffff ggggg hhhhhh iiiiiii jjjjjjjj 
 \sethlcolor{pink}
 \hl{kkkkkkkkk kkkkkkkkkkk}
 \marginpar{\scriptsize{\textbf{kkkkkkkkk kkkkkkkkkkk:} }}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT** The `\patchcmd` command simply looks inside the `\@savemarbox` command, searches for `\color@vbox` and substitutes it with `\color@vbox\normalcolor`. Of course you can avoid using `\patchcmd` by redefining `\@savemarbox` directly:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def \@savemarbox #1#2{%
  \global\setbox #1%
    \color@vbox\normalcolor% <--- added \normalcolor here ---
      \vtop{%
        \hsize\marginparwidth
        \@parboxrestore
        \@marginparreset
        #2%
        \@minipagefalse
        \outer@nobreak
        }%
    \color@endbox
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Good answer (upvoted), but a bit of explanation on what the patch does would improve the answer further.

Comment: Thank you! I edited the answer adding a very minimal explanation. In fact I can not really understand why `\normalcolor` given in other places of the \marginpar macros (for example here: `\@marbox{\normalcolor#1}`, inside `\@ympar`) changes the color but causes a bad aligned note

Comment: Thank you very very much! Your method really solve the problem perfectly!

Comment: is this really the only solution?